# use gmail to back up outlook and keep contacts

Tags: microsoft-outlook

I'd like to back up my work email to a gmail account so that I can make it more easily searchable, and not have to worry about the size restrictions set by our IT group.  It's pretty easy to set up gmail as an IMAP account in Outlook and drag email over to the gmail account.

However, there is a problem: all of the contact information for internal email addresses is getting lost when I copy it over.  All of the internal emails are marked as from "(unknown sender)".  If I use "Show Original" to look at the email source it looks like this:
From: "Smith, John"
Sender: "Smith, John"

where a normal email looks like this:
From: "Smith, John"

How can I convince Outlook to include the whole email address, and not just the person's name?

Comment: There is happening because your importing mail from another IMAP/Exchange account to an entirely different IMAP account. Unless you have a paid account with Google what you want is unlikely to be possible. I was able to find this link within 30 seconds, explain exactly how to do this, and what the requriements are: http://support.google.com/a/bin/topic.py?hl=en&topic=27378&parent=2685904&ctx=topic of using a local pst file an resolve the limits imposed on an exchange account.